# Process finished with exit code 0 java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a code in Java, which has to be able to print all the elements in an Arraylist `songs` and also be able to randomly shuffle the elements. It worked fine before but now all of the sudden it wont even print the elements. The only thing the code prints now is:

> Process finished with exit code 0

which means that my program stopped. I am thinking that It is maybe something with my for loop?

```
public void printAllSongs(){
    System.out.println("These are your current songs in your player: ");
    for (Song song : songs){
        System.out.println(song.toString());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MusicMaria player = new MusicMaria();

    player.addTrack(new Song("Timberlake", "Cry me a river", 4)); 
    player.addTrack(new Song("Shakira", "Wherever", 3));
    player.addTrack(new Song("Beyonce", "Single legs", 5));
    player.addTrack(new Song("James Brown", "It's a mans world", 3));
    player.addTrack(new Song("Ed Sheeran ", "Legohouse", 3));
    player.addTrack(new Song("Mia", "I love you", 4));
    player.addTrack(new Song("Scarlet", "Palm tree", 5));
    //player.printAllSongs();
    player.shuffle();
    player.printAllSongs();
}
```

Comment: in your for loop where is this `songs' coming from?

Comment: That's not enough. Show us the whole `MusicMaria` class including `#addTrack` and `#shuffle`. But refresh the page first, to see all applied edits.

Comment: The whole code is too long. Stack overflow wont let me submit because it contains too many letters. Is it possible to send it as a file?

Comment: Then create a [mcve].

Comment: Here is the link to the folder in Dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/sh/whhr43541u2v03j/AACJXvg7J4ftNahysx-tFDPca?dl=0

Comment: Exit code of 0 is a normal way for your program to exit. If you program isn't do what it should you can step through the code in your debugger and look at what each line of code does to find the line which is not doing what you expected.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Copying all your code from Dropbox to IDEONE, and program runs fine. See https://ideone.com/ZWd9iZ

Answer (score 2):

According to the code you have linked (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/whhr43541u2v03j/AACJXvg7J4ftNahysx-tFDPca?dl=0), the problem is in your `addTrack(Song)` method.

All you are currently doing is incrementing the total playlist length by the song's length. What you need to do is add the `Song` to the `ArrayList<Song>` object. Below is code that should fix the issue.

```
private ArrayList<Song> songs; // Initialized in constructor

@Override
public void addTrack(Song song) {
    totalLength += song.getSongLenght();
    songs.add(song);
}
```